# Outlook, POP and PST handling

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, pop3, pst

Essentially I have a client who is on hosted exchange and have decided to use POP3 to download the mail (I don't know why they don't use .OST's but anyway), they rebuilt the machine and backed up their .PST file. Now their Outlook was configured to keep mail downloaded on the server for 14days.

Essentially their current PST is fairly complex, many folders and sub folders and so on. So what is the best way to handle it really - create a new Outlook profile on the rebuilt machine and download the mail via POP into a new .PST then just recreate the folders in the new pst and drag and drop the mail via attaching the backed up .pst, recreating the folders etc?

But is their an easier way to do this, maybe pointing the new account to use the original PST, but then that would download all the mail again from the server to that .PST file.

Any ideas on the best way to handle POP3 account rebuilds from scratch when you have a backed up PST?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My instinct would be to recommend trying IMAP instead, it's better at synchronizing the client with the server but if that's not available why not try this:

1. Move all Inbox mail from the Original PST File into a new Original_Inbox folder
2. Setup the new Outlook profile with the Original PST File
3. Allow it to download the POP mail into the Inbox folder
4. Delete any duplicate Inbox mail
5. Move the Original_Inbox mail back to the Inbox folder.

That's the best I can think of without IMAP.